# Getting an ASP.Net application on an Apache Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, networking, apache2, amazon-ec2

I know this sounds like a long shot, but is this possible? I'd like to do this without using Mono so I can use Visual Studio and have all of the latest nitty gritties. I'm just not a fan of Windows Server; I feel more powerful using a command line in Linux, especially with Amazon ec2.

Comment: If you don't like windows server then don't use C# or .NET when programming. I was able to create powershell modules using C# that simulate the same behavior of the linux command line interface. I use CloudInit.NET for bootstrapping the machines. No problems using windows. Still prefer using linux like yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Visual Studio with Mono.... If you compile your code in Windows with Visual Studio your assemblies will run on Mono.

So you could easily deploy an EC2 Linux instance and setup your website with Apache2 and [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono). Then upload all of your assemblies and template files to your EC2 instance and you will be in business.